# How to extract text from between tags?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping, robobrowser

I'm using robobrowser to scraping this page, inside the page there's a `textarea` tag with information that I need to copy and store.

This is my code:

```
>>> captchacode = captchabrowser.find('textarea')
>>> print(captchacode)
<textarea cols="100" rows="5">03AHJ_VuvjiQUpaQ-JFLXqAJaUQ217f7bHqa3hG__VSG1YsbjNtsT2FGFrJksCansOxwuxniksyCsnHJTvlCeGdi2jeqUyuDfUGAQ1WIuJqO55ACslBSUnd-MtAMDIOmbTa1G9uh1QMBdZUTRXwmt1kOn7oNf6ZflnUGAtIOGeTSgx-wu8hOWY-Pw</textarea>
```

How do I get the text from

```
<textarea cols="100" rows="5">XXXXXX</textarea>
```

I need the `XXXXX` in a variable by them selves.

Comment: There's a formatting error in that putting data "inside" a textarea is bad HTML. It should be `<textarea value="XXXXX"></textarea>` , just be aware of that.

Comment: @aarongillion the website where i scrape from has it like that and i cant change it :(

Comment: That's fine, I was just pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick test, using python2.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='<textarea cols="100" rows="5">03AHJ_VuvjiQUpaQ-JFLXqAJaUQ217f7bHqa3hG__VSG1YsbjNtsT2FGFrJksCansOxwuxniksyCsnHJTvlCeGdi2jeqUyuDfUGAQ1WIuJqO55ACslBSUnd-MtAMDIOmbTa1G9uh1QMBdZUTRXwmt1kOn7oNf6ZflnUGAtIOGeTSgx-wu8hOWY-Pw</textarea>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
ta = soup.find('textarea')
if ta:
  print ta.get_text()
else:
  print "no such element"
```

which outputs:

```
03AHJ_VuvjiQUpaQ-JFLXqAJaUQ217f7bHqa3hG__VSG1YsbjNtsT2FGFrJksCansOxwuxniksyCsnHJTvlCeGdi2jeqUyuDfUGAQ1WIuJqO55ACslBSUnd-MtAMDIOmbTa1G9uh1QMBdZUTRXwmt1kOn7oNf6ZflnUGAtIOGeTSgx-wu8hOWY-Pw
```

If you only have one textarea, you can use `find`, otherwize, use `find_all`.

Comment: I get that as well but when i try setting my = ta.get_text()   my always returns None

Comment: In which scope did you assign `my`?

Comment: im not sure what that means, i did this 
my = ta.get_text()
print(my)

Comment: Edit your original question then.